# Select record when it is the only record and not linked to in another table to a particular record

Tags: sql

I am looking to select the id of a record from @table1 when that record is the only record in that table and is not currently linked in @t1Tot2 to a particular id from another table.

The following query below works, but I am wondering if there is a better way.  It is setup to currently to return 55 the id of the only record added to table @table1.  Inserting another record into @table1 would cause it to return no records ( good ), and linking @t2id in @t1Tot2 would make it return none as well ( good ).  Is there a better way?  Thanks.

```
DECLARE @t2id INT
SET @t2id = 1 --Record to link to
DECLARE @table1 TABLE
(
t1id int
)
DECLARE @t1Tot2 TABLE
(
t1id INT,
t2id int
)
INSERT INTO @table1
( t1id )
VALUES  ( 55  -- t1id - int
)

--Will cause the query below to return no records because of having more than 1 record to be linked to
--  INSERT INTO @table1
--        ( t1id )
--VALUES  ( 2  -- t1id - int
--          )    

--Will cause the query below to return no records because of already being linked to the t1id
--INSERT INTO @t1Tot2
--( t1id, t2id )
--VALUES  ( 55, -- t1id - int
--@t2id  -- t2id - int
--)    

SELECT MAX(a.t1id)
FROM @table1 a
LEFT JOIN @t1Tot2 b ON a.t1id = b.t1id AND b.t2id = 1
HAVING COUNT(1) = 1 AND SUM( CASE WHEN b.t2id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ) = 0
```

Comment: Actually, this did not work if both commented inserts are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
--declare @table1 table (t1id int)
--declare @t1Tot2 table (t1id int)

select a.t1id
from @table1 a
where (select count(*) from (select top 2 * from @table1) x) = 1
and not exists (
    select * from @t1Tot2 b
    where b.t1id = a.t1id)
```

Comment: I updated the query I was using as an example. It works in the same scenarios but the execution plan is smaller.  Do you see any issues with the new query?

Comment: @Thx without looking too closely at your query, LEFT JOIN normally doesn't work as well as EXISTS. However, if your tables are both always small, the difference is negligible and only academic. I would have written the last line `HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 AND COUNT(b.t2id) = 0`

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.aid
from a
left outer join b on a.bid=b.bid
where b.bid is null
group by a.aid
having count(*) = 1
```

should work as well *sql server* specific sql btw.

Comment: select MAX(a.t1id)
from @table1 a
left outer join @t1Tot2 b on a.t1id=b.t1id AND b.t2id is null
having count(*) = 1

I moved the b.t2id into the join constraint

Comment: i want to join on a.aid = b.aid and want no records if there are any links for a b.bid

Comment: that's why it's a left outer where b.bid is null (basically join all records in A with what it can find in B and then strip out the ones that aren't in B).  Then use the group by + having to filter out the ones where there is only one record in A.  You don't want to and the bid is null because that will impact the join rather than filter the records. And max(a.aid) is not the same as only finding one, that's finding ONE record (which rereading your original query that's what you want, but I'd be pretty careful doing that since you could have weird data, but you know your system better than me.

Comment: That won't work because I am basically looking to return a record from a when it is both the only record in a, and it is not already linked to a specific b.bid in table b.

Comment: Can you give a data example, because my understanding is this: B has three records ([aid:1], [aid:2], [aid:3]).  B has 2 records: ([bid:11, aid:1], [bid:22, aid:1]).  You want the query to return aid:2 and aid:3 (because they don't have any records in B). select a.aid from a left outer join b on b.aid=a.aid where b.bid is null will return just that.  You keep throwing in this request about non dupe aids, but that's not entirely clear.  Perhaps giving a simplified table structure in your original post will clarify things.

Comment: Sorry I could have been more clear.  I was looking to either return 0 records or, 1 record meeting the conditions that it is the only record in table a, and if it is the only record in table a it is also not currently linked in table atob for a particular bid.